# blkdiscard hangs on md raid 10 on PCIe SSDs

Tags: mdadm, ssd, block-device, trim, util-linux

I have a running Linux 4.19 amd64 system with two PCIe SSDs that I'd like to clear, test, reformat and put in use again. All of the data has already been moved away. I've

- tried to trim/discard blocks from the SSD devices `/dev/sdX` with `hdparm`, but it said that the devices "do not support SSD TRIM".
- tested the random R/W speed with different block sizes - successfully
- created md RAID 10 (far 2) `/dev/md/ssd` taking care of chunk sizes / alignment
- just to test, created an ext4 FS over the RAID and it showed that it was discarding the device blocks, which did take some time (as I would expect).
- Encouraged by that I've unmounted the FS and then issued

  `blkdiscard -v /dev/md/ssd`

  but it did not produce any output and is blocked (state `D`) since more than 12 hours. Reading from `/dev/md/ssd` is still possible, writing few blocks to the start was/is possible, but following writes are blocked (`D+`) since hours.

Killing `blkdiscard`, with `TERM` or `KILL` does apparently nothing.
Stopping the RAID is not possible, `mdadm` reports that it is busy - in use by the `blkdiscard` process.

Are there any options to resolve that short of rebooting the system? (Rebooting is costly because I'd drive to the site, just in case...)

Answer (score 1):

You may wait and hope the operation will eventually time out and AFAIK the only option you've got left is `hdparm -w /dev/device` which would perform a drive reset.

**But be careful!** `man hdparm` say the following about `-w`:

> Perform  a  device reset (DANGEROUS).  Do NOT use this option.  It exists for unlikely situations where a reboot might otherwise be required to get a confused drive back into a useable state.